# LOGIN FORM THE USER ID IS SHOWING INSTEAD OF USERNAME

Tags: ms-access

THIS IS MY CODE PLS HELp

({How To SHow THe Username!!})

the UserID always showing Instead of Username
I think a Have a Missed Code pls help
This is for my Finals
all my form are finish but im stuck in login form

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub BTNCancel_Click()
Dim Ans As String

Ans = MsgBox("Do you want to cancel log-in?", vbYesNo, "Shutdown the system")

If Ans = vbYes Then
DoCmd.Quit

Else
    Exit Sub
End If




End Sub
Private Sub CBOEmployee_AfterUpdate()
'After selecting user name set focus to password field
    Me.TXTPassword.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub BTNLogin_Click()

If IsNull(Me.CBOEmployee) Or Me.CBOEmployee = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must Enter a User Name.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
    Me.CBOEmployee.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If

   If IsNull(Me.TXTPassword) Or Me.TXTPassword = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must Enter a Password.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
    Me.TXTPassword.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If
If Me.TXTPassword.Value = DLookup("UserPassword", "tblUsers", "[UserID] =" & Me.CBOEmployee.Value) Then

UserID = Me.CBOEmployee.Value


DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmLogon"
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmStudSubject"
Else
MsgBox "Password Invalid. Please Try Again", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Entry!"
Me.TXTPassword.SetFocus
End If

intLogonAttempts = intLogonAttempts + 1
If intLogonAttempts > 3 Then
    MsgBox "You are unauthorized to access this system...Please Contact Your  System Administrator.", vbCritical, "Restricted access!"
    Application.Quit
    End If




End Sub
```

Comment: **PLEASE DON'T SHOUT AT US!!** Don't use ALL CAPS - it's considered SHOUTING and it's rude. Also: you should **ASK a question** and not just dump a pile of code on us.... what does the code do? What does it do wrong? Show us what you're trying to do and where you're stuck! [Please read this post](http://www.tinyurl.com/so-hints) to learn how to ask a **GOOD** question on SO!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Sorry for wrong Asking but i really have a Help so if you know what i wrong to my code pls answer.. :)

Comment: As I said: you need to **ask a question** - not just dump code on us! What is wrong with the code? Where do you have a problem, and **what is** that problem?

Comment: My question how to show the username instead of userid

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the username should be shown in CBOEmployee. If it shows the UserId instead it's a problem with the ColumnWidth property of that control.

If collapsed, a ComboBox shows the text of the first column having a non-zero width in the ColumnWidth-list.

Typically, the RowSource returns a recordset with some id in the first column, and the text to display in the second column. Then, the ColumnWidth property looks similar to "0,1.23".